# how to insert text in images sequentially in a directory

Tags: bash, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have tried the following:

```
n=1
for index in image*.png; 
do convert $index -fill white  -undercolor '#00000080'  -gravity South -pointsize 44 -annotate +0+550 “image`echo $n`”;
((n++)); 
done
```

This results in an error:

> convert:  `“image1”' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3272.

and so on till the end of all image files in the directory.

Basically I'm trying to insert text as the filename in the image.

Comment: You have wrong quotes: ““ .  Use straight quotes: ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plain double quotes around “image`echo $n`” have been replaced by opening/closing double quotes(*). Also, the `echo` is unnecessary, try `"image$n.png"`

(*) possibly the deed of an editor not meant to edit code, editing with Wordpad perhaps?